# Is it possible to generate help tags with readonly '/usr'?

Tags: help-system

I have readonly `/usr` partition and `:helptags` returns an error about not being able to write to `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc`. Is it possible to specify additional/another directory for help tags?

Comment: You normally shouldn't be trying to put help tags into `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc`. That directory already contains a `tags` file. Any plugins that you install should go into your `~/.vim` directory and the resulting help tags into `~/.vim/doc`. Do that by executing `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`. See `:help add-local-help`.

Comment: If that answers it, then I'll make my command a real answer so that we don't leave your question in the unanswered state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally shouldn't be trying to put help tags into `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc`. That directory already contains a `tags` file. Any plugins that you install should go into your `~/.vim` directory and the resulting help tags into `~/.vim/doc`. Do that by executing

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

See

```
:help add-local-help
```

Just to round out the answer, if you're adding plugins for use by all users and not just you, you could put them in `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` and build a help tags file there with

```
:helptags /usr/share/vimfiles/doc
```

That wouldn't work in your particular case, though, because you wouldn't be able to write to that directory, either.